# Как вытащить названия химических веществ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, natasha

Есть файлы отчётов Росгидромета «Об аварийном, экстремально высоком и высоком загрязнении окружающей среды,
а также радиационной обстановке на территории России в <месяц> <года> года» с 2008 по 2021 год.

Нужно вытащить оттуда место, превышение ПДК и название химического вещества.

Нужные абзацы примерно такие:

> Случай высокого загрязнения (ВЗ)** атмосферного воздуха веществом 1 класса опасности - бенз(а)пиреном, был зарегистрирован в Архангельске (1 случай, 13 ПДКм.р.).

> В апреле 2020 года на территории Российской Федерации случаи ЭВЗ поверхностных вод веществами 1-го и 2-го классов опасности (превышение ПДК** в 5 и
> более раз) наблюдательной сетью Росгидромета были зарегистрированы 19 раз на                        5 водных объектах (для сравнения: в апреле  2019 года – 5 раз на 4 водных объектах).

Slovnet и Navec выделяют только места и организации, а веществ («азотом нитритным») — нет. Можно ведь как-нибудь их вытащить?

```
                 LOC  LOC──────────────          LOC─                 
    Бугульмы Республики Татарстан было зарегистрировано высокое 
             LOC─────────────────                               
    загрязнение (ВЗ) речной воды азотом нитритным (12 ПДК). По данным ФГБУ
                                                                      ORG─
     «УГМС Республики Татарстан» Росгидромета, ВЗ было обусловлено 
    ───────────────────────────  ORG─────────  OR                  
    поступлением в реку недостаточно очищенных сточных вод с очистных 
    сооружений ООО «Водоканал» г. Бугульмы Республики Татарстан.
               ORG────────────             LOC─────────────────
```

Comment: А во втором абзаце что оно должно вытащить? Там и человеку то понять не просто. Напишите подробнее в вопросе, что вы хотите видеть на выходе хотя бы для данных вами же примеров.

Comment: Тут, скорее, я неправилный пример привёл, потому что РГМ иногда даёт такой текст и таблички.

Для остальных хочется получить, например:
— Архангельск, бенз(а)пиарен, 13
—  Бугульма, азот нитритный, 12